# Fetch Multiple records from the Table matching the conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, logic

I have two table called OFFICE_GROUP and OFFICE_IPS,

[image: OFFICE_GROUP]

[image: OFFICEIPS]

I would like to get the result like get 4 rows like :
[image: RESULT]

Query used is this:

```
SELECT (SELECT oip.IP as IP FROM OFFICE_IPS oip, OFFICE_GROUP og WHERE og.OFFICE_GROUP_ID = oip.OFFICE_GROUP_ID
         AND og.MODULES like '%1%' lIMIT 1) AS SEMINAR,
(SELECT oip.IP as IP FROM OFFICE_IPS oip, OFFICE_GROUP og WHERE og.OFFICE_GROUP_ID = oip.OFFICE_GROUP_ID
         AND og.MODULES like '%2%'  lIMIT 1)  AS FAQ,
(SELECT oip.IP as IP FROM OFFICE_IPS oip, OFFICE_GROUP og WHERE og.OFFICE_GROUP_ID = oip.OFFICE_GROUP_ID
         AND og.GRP_LIMIT like '%1%'  lIMIT 1)  AS DEV_MODE,
(SELECT oip.IP as IP FROM OFFICE_IPS oip, OFFICE_GROUP og WHERE og.OFFICE_GROUP_ID = oip.OFFICE_GROUP_ID
         AND og.GRP_LIMIT like '%2%'  lIMIT 1)  AS META_API,
(SELECT oip.IP as IP FROM OFFICE_IPS oip, OFFICE_GROUP og WHERE og.OFFICE_GROUP_ID = oip.OFFICE_GROUP_ID
         AND og.GRP_LIMIT like '%3%'  lIMIT 1)  AS TRADING_SIGNAL
```

**But** what if i want to get multiple rows, i mean if the subqueries are returning multiple rows.

In the above query if i remove the '...LIMIT 1' then, getting the error like 
*#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row*

Anybody, please help me.

Comment: Why subquery why not join ?

Comment: @dianuj, Thanks for your comments, i am learning mysql, so if you give a rough idea of  how to convert this to joins would be great

Comment: See my answer query with join

Answer (score 0):

You should do the subquery in the FROM part of your top level query and not in the SELECT.
Try to do it like

```
SELECT seminar, faq, dev_mode, meta_api, trading_signal 
FROM (subselect) as seminars_table, (subselect) as faq_table.... 
WHERE join_contition_1 and join_condition_1;
```

The Subselects then need to contain the join columns.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with join

```
SELECT oip.IP AS SEMINAR ,oip.IP AS FAQ ,oip.IP AS DEV_MODE ,oip.IP AS META_API
,oip.IP AS TRADING_SIGNAL
FROM OFFICE_IPS oip
INNER JOIN og.OFFICE_GROUP_ID = oip.OFFICE_GROUP_ID    
WHERE ( og.MODULES LIKE '%1%' OR  og.MODULES LIKE  '%2%' ) 
AND  (og.GRP_LIMIT LIKE '%1%' OR  og.GRP_LIMIT LIKE '%2%' 
OR og.GRP_LIMIT LIKE '%3%' )
```